# Does X-definition possess an instruction similar to xsl:value-of in XSLT?

Tags: java, xslt, xpath

I put Saxon on my classpath so that it was subsequently available for the [X-definition](https://github.com/Syntea/xdef) API to discover, but in order for the results of my Xpath 3.1 expressions to be shown consistently, it was necessary that I fall back on Xpath's `serialize()` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xd:def xmlns:xd="http://www.xdef.org/xdef/4.0" name="frontend" root="code">
<xd:declaration>
String myxpathexpression = "let $b := 'away I go' return (0 to string-length($b)) ! ('&#10;' || substring($b,1,string-length($b) - .))";
String valueofmyxpathexpression = "serialize(" + myxpathexpression + ")";
</xd:declaration>
<code xd:script="occurs +;init {outln(xpath(valueofmyxpathexpression));}"/>
<!--<code xd:script="occurs +;init {outln(xpath(myxpathexpression));}"/>-->
</xd:def>
```

(As a comment posted in response to this question has since established, the Xpath expression used in the above code happened to already not be up to the task it ostensibly had set for itself. Because the Xpath expression furnished by Martin Honnen in his  comment takes full account of the sequence of items returned where the previous expression can have taken barely any, the code printed below can afford to dispense with the expedient that was resorted to before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xd:def xmlns:xd="http://www.xdef.org/xdef/4.0" name="frontend" root="code">
<xd:declaration>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171810/does-x-definition-possess-an-instruction-similar-to-xslvalue-of-in-xslt -->
String myxpathexpression = "string-join(let $b := 'away I go' return (0 to string-length($b)) ! ('&#10;' || substring($b,1,string-length($b) - .)), ' ')";
</xd:declaration>
<code xd:script="occurs +;init {outln(xpath(myxpathexpression));}"/>
</xd:def>
```

Apologies are needless to say offered for having permitted poor code to distract from a question others could well wish to ask in future).

(Both articles of code were run by piping `echo "<code/>"` to the Java command and assigning `/dev/stdin` as the source of the XML).

When the line where the variable bound to the Xpath expression itself (`myxpathexpression`) was passed to X-script's `xpath()` function is uncommented (and the corresponding line commented out), it seems that a second parameter to `xpath()` is implied and that the function is really designed to populate a `Container` based on the data available from an `Element` or the like, rather than to  populate one with the items produced by an Xpath expression *per se*. It did not look feasible to pass `null` explicitly as the second parameter.

Have I overlooked anything in X-definition's XML vocabulary or its X-script language that shall work similarly to XSLT's `xsl:value-of` instruction? I have consulted the user documentation, including the Lexicon, to the best of my ability, but it unfortunately is not at all unlike me to miss things out the more they are obvious.

Comment: Are there any tags related to the technology (xdef, x-script) you seem to use? I don't see how people knowing XPath or XSLT can answer questions to a different language embedding XPath if they don't know the host language. So consider to add tags for those languages you are primarily using to make sure someone with expertise in that areas sees it.

Comment: If the general question is how to get a single string from a sequence of string items in XPath 2 or 3 the `string-join(let $b := 'away I go' return (0 to string-length($b)) ! ('&#10;' || substring($b,1,string-length($b) - .)), ' ')` might be a way instead of needing serialize.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thank you ever so much! The fact of the matter was that my Xpath code was written in the very first place with insufficient regard for the consequences of producing a sequence of items. It didn't occur to me at all that the best coding practice would have amounted to in effect finishing what I was starting by ensuring that both the type of item the sequence comprised, and the sequence's extent, would not prove a hindrance irrespective of the API being used (here, it had hinged all along on an alias for java.io.PrintStream.println()). I can only thank you again!

Comment: In regard to the tags, it didn't look like one pertaining to X-definition had been introduced to date. I hope that the link I added is an improvement. The Github project does appear to itself bear the name "xdef" rather than "X-definition"; `xdef` also serves as a Java identifier for the top level in the package hierarchy (`org.xdef`), and in the examples  one finds `.xdef` used as a file extension. A convention followed in the documentation uses an uppercase X and a hyphen followed by a lowercase (and not by an uppercase) letter to identify the application or parts of it, e.g. X-script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Saxon on your classpath you can use the method "xquery" instead of "xpath". Then you can use full XQuery language. Then the following command will work correctly in the code from your question:

```
<code xd:script="occurs +;init {outln(xquery(myxpathexpression));}"/>
```

Note you can try it on the web:

http://xdef.syntea.cz/tutorial/examples/validate.html